# Fallback for CSS3's background-size

Tags: css, background, internet-explorer-7, size, fallback

I am trying to make my site compatible with IE7. Initialy i used `background-size: contain` to fit the backgroun inside an `<a>` element. But IE7 does not support CSS3. So my question is: Is there a way to resize the background through CSS or i have to resize the .png images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

and replace sizing method and image with what you want